# Consecutive Date Formula

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am trying to insert a formula which identifies if a customer tried to contact us within 2 consecutive date.

Example:

```
Customer Date
A        10/02/19
B        10/02/19
A        11/02/019
```

So customer A called in two consecutive date.

Does anyone know what formula I can use?

Comment: Sort data by customer. Then use an `=IF()` formula to return 1 if the customer is equal to the customer in the above row and if there is 1 day between dates. This algorithm might work.

Comment: Try something like =IF(AND(C1>=A1,C1<=B1),"Yes","") , this assumes date A is in cell A1 and second date is in B1, while C1 has the actual contact date.

Comment: Can you tell us if the data is already sorted into order (ideally customer then date) plz? And how many lines of data are there?

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting the list you could use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10="A")*COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"A",B2:B10,B2:B10-1))
```

[image]